# Resources for questions related to specific software

Tags: discussion

From time to time we get questions related to specific software such as (but not limited to) Gmsh or ParaView. Depending on the type of question it might on topic here or not. This post is not about revisiting the policy for off-topic/on-topic questions (although we should discuss that as well) but related to creating some resources to help redirect people to the right places like specific forums/mailing lists/Q&A sites.

What do you think about this idea?

Comment: I think it would be good idea to have collection of other forums that could be useful for related, but possibly off-topic questions. Would this done as post on the main site, with maybe some locks in place to ensure a particular format? Or would it be better just as Meta post?

Comment: I agree. But I'm not sure where is better placed, probably here.

Comment: Depending on how extensive it will be, a format [like this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry) could work (Meta or main). Alternatively, we were trying to set up [community promotion](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/mmse-community-promotion-board) board on Matter Modeling SE and post per forum could work nice if there are just a few.